# Auto-Linking framework not found Realm

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app, and suddenly i got following errors. I have those frameworks imported by carthage directly in project.

In my ViewController class i just paste:

```
import Alamofire

print(AlamofireVersionNumber)

ld: warning: Auto-Linking framework not found Realm
ld: warning: Auto-Linking framework not found Alamofire
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AlamofireVersionNumber", referenced from:
      ChpuDemo.ViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did try to clean, delete derived data etc. What does that errors mean?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @JulianPomper please check answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solve issue by adding the same framework via CocoaPods for main project, that duplicate the same framework that was in my custom library.